# How do you write code on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have just started experimenting with WordPress, but I have not been able to figure out how to write any code whatsoever. All it gives me is built in blog stuff, and I don't want that. How do I write code on WordPress?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: "All it gives me is built in blog stuff, and I don't want that."

Then why are you using Wordpress?

Comment: What experiments have you carried out already? Tell us what you're trying to do.

Comment: I just realized that wordpress.com and wordpress.org are 2 different things. I was being an idiot

Comment: Ah, a common mistake :)

Comment: your answer is very useful to the masses though, so i am going to select it and close this question

Comment: @APAD1 Sorry. What I meant is I wanted MORE than that. The blog features are pretty sweet, actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what do you want to achieve?

Are you trying to write code that performs a function that the WordPress core doesn't provide? If so, then you should start by reading [Writing a Plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

If however you'd like to design your own look and feel, then you'd need to create a theme. The best way to do this would be to write a child theme. Start by reading about [Child Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).